# Using Structs to organize code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I recently ran across some code during a review that baffled me a bit. The dev was using structs to organize code within a larger file. I personally don't like the practice but wanted to hear others thoughts.

Assumptions: 
This was an ASP.MVC app with several app specific areas. 
The Settings.CS file has a lot of different properties specific to the app.

Example:

```
 public class Settings
        {


            private static Lazy<Settings> _Settings = new Lazy<Settings>(() => new Settings());

            public static Settings Instance
            {
                 get { return _Settings.Value; }
            }


            public OtherSettings otherSettings;
            public MoreSettings moreSettings;

            public struct OtherSettings
            {
                public string OtherConnectionString { get; set; }
            }

            public struct MoreSettings
            {
                public string ConnectionString2 { get; set; }
            }
        }
```

The structs are being used as a way to separate the code between different app areas, but to me provided no functional benefit. In no area did I see the structs being passed directly.

Example how they were being used:

```
 // Some Other Accessing Class ...
 var c = Settings.Instance.moreSettings.ConnectionString2;
```

They were simply being used as a 'pseudo namespace'.

I would much rather see more specific settings.cs IE: AppSettings.cs, AppSettings2.cs in their respective namespaces.

Comment: Just seen this: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12849

Comment: @Den Yeah good find. I don't like that proposal much better than the practice above. But Yea, that's based on the same principle.

Comment: Are these literally one property structs or are there more properties per struct in the real code?

Comment: @RubberDuck Nah, they have more in production. Sorry :)

Comment: Then it's likely entirely reasonable @Botonomous

Comment: @RubberDuck Thanks for the reply. To me this goes against what a struct is though. Am I just being too conservative or is this an accepted practice?

Comment: @Botonomous it's a bad practice. It's misusing types, misusing value types and violating SOLID. Not to mention the singleton anti-pattern. Basically a normal .NET codebase :).

Comment: @Den A singleton is a pattern, yes. Not an anti-pattern, however. Lot's of people _don't like it_, but being _not liked_ doesn't mean it's bad. There are legitimate uses for it.

Comment: @ThalesPereira, a singleton is most definitely an anti-pattern. Some people just don't *like* to hear this.

Comment: Worth reading the language proposal that @Den links to. Note the large number of down-votes. Using types like this to create extended namespaces is an indication that the class has too many responsibilities. It's bad design.

Comment: Undoubtedly not a good design @DavidArno, but it's a step toward breaking that big class up into single responsibilities. For all we know, this is step two of a larger refactoring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examples with terms like "Foo", "Bar", "Other" and "More" are seldom helpful when it comes to design issues. So lets assume the "real" code looks more like this:

```
 public struct NetworkSettings
 {
      public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
      public ProtocolType Protocol { get; set; }
      public double Timeout { get; set; }
 }

 public struct DatabaseSettings
 { 
       public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
 }
```

(could be also classes instead of structs, but for this case, it does not make a big difference).

This might not be the "perfect", final design, but at least it is better than having a bunch of single variables like

```
   public string NetworkConnectionString { get; set; }
   public NetworkProtocolType Protocol { get; set; }
   public double NetworkTimeout { get; set; }
   public string DatabaseConnectionString { get; set; }
```

So the `struct` names at least provide meaningful group names, and the parameters have a meaning which become more clear when seen within their specific context. If that is your case, the answer is "yes, this makes sense" - because the code gets more readable.

Of course, this is not an end in itself - when each of the structs just contains a single value, or the names are not clarifying, or the group names seem to be artificial, then the grouping looses its benefits and one would better off to remove it or find a better grouping.

Comment: When I see this code there are three options in my mind: a) those types are instantiated and mutated in local scopes often enough to warrant micro-optimisations; b) those are "true" well-defined generic domain value types; c) misuse of structures.

Comment: @Den: you are surely correct the design could improved further, but my point is a different one. The question is not about finding an even more SOLID solution, it is about a worse alternative approach of using no grouping at all. See my edit.

Comment: I'm used to `struct`s having some reason to exist that is semantically consistent with a `struct`, such as value-type characteristics or word alignment mechanics.  If I saw these particular structs, I would wonder why the programmer chose `struct` over `class`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: of course, C# programmers like us would typically pick a "class" by default, and a struct only when needed. But for the purpose of this question it does no matter (and it saves the need for `otherSettings = new OtherSettings();`, which would only add "noise" to the code).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I agree with you, but I am glad I received some other views on this practice as well. I went ahead and let them leave the code in because I didn't see any harm in allowing it.  Thanks for your help everyone. Accepting this answer although they all are great.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this used as well. A possible reason is that with say 10+ settings, it becomes hard to pick the right one even with Intellisense. But if they're broken up by category/ subcategories, when you type "." to get Intellisense predictions you only get 3-4, then you can drill down by area.

It's just a way of making things easy for the client user

And since there's a singleton holding ALL settings, the likelihood of having many properties is high. So it helps to organize them. Sure they could have defined 5 difference classes for different types of settings but it just makes things that much more confusing, now you need to hunt down class names

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with you that "the structs are being used as a way to separate the code between different app areas" and serve like "pseudo namespaces".

Based on this belief, my guess is that the developer was using a struct, a value type, instead of a class, a reference type, to prevent the need to write code to instantiate class instances for your fields.  For example, if the "otherSettings" and "moreSettings" fields from your sample code had been class types, you would need to instantiate the classes before accessing the fields like so:

```
 // Initialize class field values
 otherSettings = new OtherSettings();
 moreSettings = new MoreSettings();

 ...

 // Access fields after instantiation from some other class
 var c = Settings.Instance.moreSettings.ConnectionString2;
 var c2 = Settings.Instance.otherSettings.OtherConnectionString;
```

Instead, as struct types, the fields don't need instantiation and can be directly accessed like so:

```
 // Access fields without needing any instantiations
 var c = Settings.Instance.moreSettings.ConnectionString2;
```

By using structs, the developer wouldn't need to do the class instantiations and save a few keystrokes.

Personally, if the usage was limited and purely for "pseudo namespace" purposes, I don't see an issue with doing it this way as it simplifies coding.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to keeping the scope of subtypes local, which is good, the value types allow for more effective serializing were the settings to be persisted to a file. The use of structs is appropriate since settings are merely a bunch of value types anyway and do not represent a problem domain entity that needs class features. So I salute this approach and would consider using it myself.